# Parsing regular strings into a tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

How can I store these details in a tuple  in a certain order.
Strings to store:

```
3445 3332r IT Ron Mose Don Simpson    
3446 2334f Teacher Hezen Mike Rob    
3447 2344g Writer Mike Robert
```

Each line should be stored in a tuple which should only contain 5 items which are: `ID, reference, job, otherNames, Surname`.

eg The surname is the last name eg in the first line `3445` is the `ID`, `3332r` is the `reference`, `IT` is the `job`, `Ron Mose Don` is the `other names` and `Simpson` is the `surname`.

So the first line should be like **3445 , 3332r , IT , Ron Mose Don, Simpson**

or line 2 should be stored as **3446, 2334f, Teacher, Hezen Mike, Rob**

or the last line should be a tuple as **3447 ,2344g, Writer, Mike, Robert**

Comment: I would have a look at namedtuple, although tuples are intrinsically ordered:
https://pymotw.com/2/collections/namedtuple.html

Namedtuples allow you to assign fields to each position, so you can access by position or field name (so 0, or ID, for example).

Comment: Do you want to store them in a text file or just in memory?

Comment: Basically create and return a tuple with a similar string

Comment: 3446 2334f Teacher Hezen Mike Rob       --- >  Line  -- create tuple like <--                                                   3446,2334f ,Teacher, Hezen Mike, Rob       when i search for Mike the function should returh the tuple with mike in it such as    3446,2334f ,Teacher, Hezen Mike, Rob

Comment: Create a tuple, and there's 5 items in it. For example `(3445 , 3332r, IT, Ron Mose Don, Simpson)`. Right?

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: yh  the tuple should has 5 items like that

Comment: version 3.4.1 which i think is the latest version

Comment: 3.4.1 is not the latest version.

Comment: Basically the whole thing is, I have a txt file with info on each line eg  3445 3332r IT Ron Mose Don Simpson    
3446 2334f Teacher Hezen Mike Rob    
3447 2344g Writer Mike Robert    I tryed to create a function that can read the txt file and  put each line into a tuple and each tuple can only contain 5 items which are the ID, Reference, Job, OtherNames, Surname eg for the first line it should be (3445,3332r ,IT, Ron Mose Don ,Simpson) .When i search for a string eg Ron , it returns the Rons Tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split each string, then unpack it into the structure you want. Rejoin the `otherNames` into a single string.

```
l = ['3445 3332r IT Ron Mose Don Simpson',
     '3446 2334f Teacher Hezen Mike Rob',
     '3447 2344g Writer Mike Robert']
result = [(a, b, c, ' '.join(d), e) for a, b, c, *d, e in (item.split() for item in l)]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(*result, sep='\n')
('3445', '3332r', 'IT', 'Ron Mose Don', 'Simpson')
('3446', '2334f', 'Teacher', 'Hezen Mike', 'Rob')
('3447', '2344g', 'Writer', 'Mike', 'Robert')
```

Comment: I love Python 3's unpacking feature. I'm still using 2.7.x.

Comment: Basically the whole thing is, I have a txt file with info on each line eg 3445 3332r IT Ron Mose Don Simpson 3446 2334f Teacher Hezen Mike Rob 3447 2344g Writer Mike Robert I tryed to create a function that can read the txt file and put each line into a tuple and each tuple can only contain 5 items which are the ID, Reference, Job, OtherNames, Surname eg for the first line it should be (3445,3332r ,IT, Ron Mose Don ,Simpson) .When i search for a string eg Ron , it returns the Rons Tuple

Comment: What you have done is good. Now how can i make it a function that when i search for a key eg Ron the function return the Rons tuple

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Specific questions are acceptable, but "now make the rest of the whole program for me" is not.

Comment: I guess you guys are right .Thanks for the help tho guys. I should have made the question a bit more specific. Am gonna ask the same question in a new question but be more specific. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

Is this you want?

```
def create_tuple(string):
    l = string.split()
    return (*l[:3], ' '.join(l[3:-1]), l[-1])
```

Demo:

```
>>> create_tuple('3445 3332r IT Ron Mose Don Simpson')
('3445', '3332r', 'IT', 'Ron Mose Don', 'Simpson')

>>> create_tuple('3446 2334f Teacher Hezen Mike Rob ')
('3446', '2334f', 'Teacher', 'Hezen Mike', 'Rob')

>>> create_tuple('3447 2344g Writer Mike Robert')
('3447', '2344g', 'Writer', 'Mike', 'Robert')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

At work, I am still running 2.7.x, so my solution works with that. My strategy is to split the first 3 tokens (id, ref, job). For the remaining tokens, the last one is the surname, the rest is the other name.

```
def tokenize(line):
    id_, ref, job, name = line.split(' ', 3)
    name, surname = name.rsplit(' ', 1)
    return id_, ref, job, name, surname

lines = """3445 3332r IT Ron Mose Don Simpson
3446 2334f Teacher Hezen Mike Rob
3447 2344g Writer Mike Robert"""

for line in lines.splitlines():
    print(tokenize(line))
```

Output:

```
('3445', '3332r', 'IT', 'Ron Mose Don', 'Simpson')
('3446', '2334f', 'Teacher', 'Hezen Mike', 'Rob')
('3447', '2344g', 'Writer', 'Mike', 'Robert')
```

Comment: Basically the whole thing is, I have a txt file with info on each line eg 3445 3332r IT Ron Mose Don Simpson 3446 2334f Teacher Hezen Mike Rob 3447 2344g Writer Mike Robert I tryed to create a function that can read the txt file and put each line into a tuple and each tuple can only contain 5 items which are the ID, Reference, Job, OtherNames, Surname eg for the first line it should be (3445,3332r ,IT, Ron Mose Don ,Simpson) .When i search for a string eg Ron , it returns the Rons Tuple

Comment: What you have done is good. Now how can i make it a function that when i search for a key eg Ron the function return the Rons tuple

Comment: Please consider a separate question for that. I am sure many (I myself included) will be glad to help.

Comment: I would actually recommend against a separate question if the question is simply going to be "write the rest of my program for me." SO is not a crowdsourced coding service.

Comment: I agree with you. In face, if you search for **Shmoikel Krustofski**, you will find many people (probably in the same class) are asking about the same problem :-)